# Incorrect tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags

The [schema](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) tag is currently a synonym of the [db-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db-api) tag.

[Schema API](http://drupal.org/node/146843) and [Database API](http://drupal.org/node/310069) refer to two separate things in Drupal (they even have separate documentation in which they are specifically referred to as separate APIs).

Can we make [schema](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) a tag in it's own right, and perhaps rename it [schema-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema-api), to better reflect its purpose?

I'm more than happy to do the leg work to go through the questions currently tagged with [db-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db-api), and re-tag appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the synonym.

I agree that [schema-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema-api) is a better tag. I remember [schema](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema) was used in questions about the database API not related with the schema API, or questions about the database. Maybe, using [schema-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema-api) would help avoiding the tag is misused.

The excerpt for the tag wiki should suggest the related tags.

Comment: Cool thanks for that. Shall I go through and re-tag the questions with [tag:schema-api] where appropriate? There's only 100 or so, won't take long

Comment: Sure; feel free to do it when you have time.